# migration from TYPO3 6 to 7 view helper error

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-7.6.x, viewhelper

I have migrated a TYPO3 6.2.31 page to TYPO3 7.6.23

Most stuff works fine.

At the moment I have the Problem with a view helper.

I got this error:

```
Could not analyse class: "FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers\SwitchViewHelper" maybe not loaded or no autoloader? Class FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers\SwitchViewHelper does not exist
```

How can I fix this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP class SwitchViewHelper has been removed between VHS version 2.4.0 & 3.0.0. Cause 3.0.0 was TYPO3 7 compatible, which includes its own SwitchViewHelper.

Depend, how you call such SwitchViewHelper in your FLUID templates - I guess something like

```
vhs:switch
```

You should change it to

```
f:switch
```

and also adapt to f:case, f:defaultCase ..

See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Switch.html

Comment: I don't use `vhs:switch`, Do I have to add a `defaultCase`?

Comment: I have removed (commented out) all `f:switch` ... but still have the same error

Comment: Then try to find the usage of FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers\SwitchViewHelper, maybe from any other vhs incompatible extension in your installation ...

Comment: it only comes on the page where I added my frontend plugin

Comment: Now I got this: `TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\ViewHelpers\DefaultCaseViewHelper`

Comment: Ah the docu you sended me was for typo3 8 .. in typo3 7 the defaultCase is like the one in typo3 6

Comment: outcommenting a VH does still load it